# Is it possible to Query MapR DB JSON table created using Drill through hive?

Tags: hive, apache-drill

I created a MapR DB JSON table using Apache Drill and I would like to query that using Hive.

Is that possible or do I need to load data to newly created MapR DB JSON Hive table ?

Let me know.

Thanks,
Pratap

Comment: Yes, you need to load data to newly created MapR DB JSON Hive table.

Note: Starting in Drill 1.14, the MapR Drill installation package includes a hive-maprdb-json-handler, which enables you to create Hive external tables from MapR-DB JSON tables and then query the tables using the Hive schema. Drill can use the native Drill reader to read the Hive external tables. The native Drill reader enables Drill to perform faster reads of data and apply filter pushdown optimizations. The hive-maprdb-json-handler is not included in the Apache Drill installation package.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a MapR DB JSON table using Apache Drill. CTAS is supported for dfs only in Drill for now, see more [1].

Drill can query MapR-DB tables directly [2]. Also it can query Hive Mapr-DB tables via Hive code (hive-maprdb-json-handler) or via Drill MapR-DB native reader for Hive tables [3].

If you already have JSON tables in MapR-DB database you can create Hive external tables for them and query them in Hive then [4].

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/ 
[2] https://drill.apache.org/docs/mapr-db-format/ 
[3] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6454 
[4] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables